# Purpose: Using Android HttpClient upload a file to tomcat server in doInBackground() of Async Task

Tags: android, apache, fileoutputstream, httpconnection, androidhttpclient

Found couple of links here and there.. But none of them worked for me.
Trying to achieve is the following :

1) I have a server specified in location server address (e.g : www.google.com:8080)

2) The server has a php script to handle the input.

3) Wanted to create a text file in the server at location /var/www/working/

4) The content is stored in a string urlFile (which is a structured json)

5) Writing the string directly to the server location rather than messing user's device

```
private class WebServiceCall extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(locationServer + "/handle.php");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            // Setting chunk improves performance
            conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
            //Enabling POST method
            ((HttpURLConnection) conn).setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);



            FileOutputStream serverWriter = new FileOutputStream(new File("/var/www/working/jsonFile.txt"), false);
            serverWriter.write(urlFile.getBytes());
            serverWriter.close();
            conn.disconnect();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Server Refused";
        }
        return "Uploaded";
    }
```

This is my code snippet, would appreciate any help.

Thanks!
Suman

Comment: And I suppose this does not work?

Comment: Yes, I get the error : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/www/working/jsonFile.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)